# Manage Multiple Data Center Clusters in cassandra

Tags: java, cassandra

I have set up Cassandra in 3 individual machines...say A,B,C , as per the documentation i did change the cassandra.yaml files of each machine like this

```
Machine A: listen_address = A's IP
   rpc_address = A's IP
   seeds = A's IP

Machine B: listen_address = B's IP
   rpc_address = B's IP
   seeds = A's IP

Machine C: listen_address = C's IP
   rpc_address = C's IP
   seeds = A's IP
```

Now if B,C any one of them are down I am not able to get records from A,which is expected to get,I am confusing in terms like node,datacenter...In above scenario I thought all are different data centers but when get ring info using nodetool;it shows them in same datacenter (datacenter1)
what I need to know is correct setup so that it utilizes Cassandra efficiently

I created keyspace in each node like

```
create keyspace test
  with placement_strategy = 'SimpleStrategy'
  and strategy_options = {replication_factor : 1}
  and durable_writes = true;
```

I didnt used any consistentcy level...

```
Datacenter: datacenter1
==========
Replicas: 1

Address     Rack        Status State   Load            Owns                Token                                       
                                                                           849583800602241121                          
B's IP      rack1       Up     Normal  156.98 KB       95.39%              0                                           
C's IP      rack1       Up     Normal  130.3 KB        4.61%               849583800602241121
```

Answer (score 2):

Setting `replication_factor` to 1 means that there is only one copy of each row, on one node. It is possible that you're trying to ask for data that resides on the failed node, which explains why you aren't seeing anything returned.

To your earlier question, a **data center** is a geographically-grouped collection of individual **nodes**. Single or multiple data centers can be combined into a single **cluster**.

Answer (score 0):

With a replication factor of 1, we can assume that A's data will be replicated in B, B's data in C and C's data in A and so if 1 machine goes down all your data should still be available [Availability in Cassandra].
What is the error that you are getting when you are trying to query the data?

For a cluster of 3 nodes (machines), a single data centre should suffice unless you are trying to test a setup across geographical locations. Basically, a set of nodes (machines) at one location comprise a data-centre. Hence, your setup is correct and the nodetool is showing the information correctly. 
Also, it is not required to create the keyspace in each node of your cluster. You can create it on any one node and when the other nodes join cluster, the schema is automatically propagated to the newly joined node.

Comment: Thanks answer helps;(1)Exception is : "May not be enough replicas present to handle consistency level" ;when B or C any one of these are down.(2)If you are saying is correct than A's IP in ring information should also be there but it isn't (3)schema is generated automatically its right..but what about data..it isnt replicated ,(data posted from C isnt available at B)

Comment: What is the consistency level for each of your write requests? For a 3 node cluster with replication factor of 1, you could have a consistency level of ONE (only one node responds for the write to be considered successful) but that depends entirely on your requirement. How are you creating the column family? Maybe for some reason, a node hasn't joined the ring. All machines in the cluster should have the same cluster_name. Also, look into the logs for some useful pointers.

Comment: I didnt used any consistentcy level..than after I set the consistency level to 1 and also checked cluster name...its same. every time I got the same info in ring as shown below in answer ,suggest any blog or document by which things and scenarios can be clarified

Comment: These are 2 different issues. Adding a consistency level of ONE has nothing to do with A not appearing in the nodetool result. You definitely need to check the /logs on A to see if there is any particular reason as to why its not starting up. Also, it is the seed node. So you should bring up A first and then the rest of the nodes B & C. If possible, trying starting A and then copy-paste a snippet of what you see in the logs to better assess the issue.